# Why does my web scraper not scrape the relevant information?

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, xpath

I have built a web scraper with python using selenium. It runs without errors and opens the requested url (even though just one page and not all).
But after the code has been run, there is no output.
The csv I create using pandas is empty.

Looking at my code, do you see, why it does not scrape the items?

```
for i in range(0, 10):
    url = 'https://ec.europa.eu/info/law/better-regulation/have-your-say/initiatives?page=' + str(i)
    driver.get(url)
    time.sleep(random.randint(1, 11))
    driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "initivative-item")
    initiative_list = []
    title = video.find_element(By.XPATH, "./html/body/app-root/ecl-app-standardised/main/div/ng-component/div/section/ux-block-content/div/initivative-item[2]/article/a/div[2]").text
    topic = video.find_element(By.XPATH, ".///html/body/app-root/ecl-app-standardised/main/div/ng-component/div/section/ux-block-content/div/initivative-item[1]/article/a/div[3]/div[2]").text
    period = video.find_element(By.XPATH, ".///html/body/app-root/ecl-app-standardised/main/div/ng-component/div/section/ux-block-content/div/initivative-item[1]/article/a/div[5]/div/div[2]").text
    initiative_item = {
        'title': [title],
        'topic': [topic],
        'period': [period]
    }

    initiative_list.extend(initiative_item)

df = pd.DataFrame(initiative_list) 
print(df) 
df.to_csv('file_name.csv')
```

I have checked the xpaths and they seem to be correct, because they do not cause any errors.

Comment: You are not creating a pandas.DataFrame, or a csv in the code provided.

Comment: thanks for your reply. I didn't add that here to make it more clear, because that does not cause the issue. I do use pandas and receive an empty csv: df = pd.DataFrame(initiative_list)
print(df)

df.to_csv('file_name.csv')

Comment: Read about https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/webdriver/waits/

Answer (score 0):

Could you confirm that your variables `title`, `topic` and `period` are not empty?

If not, isnt somewhere in your cycle initialisation of your `initiative_list` set to `initiative_list = []` ?
That will remove all of the content already appended to your list.

Comment: Thanks for your response.
This is the outcome, if that helps:

C:\Users\JRGN1\PycharmProjects\pythonProject2\venv\Scripts\python.exe C:\Users\JRGN1\PycharmProjects\pythonProject2\main.py 
C:\Users\JRGN1\PycharmProjects\pythonProject2\main.py:7: DeprecationWarning: executable_path has been deprecated, please pass in a Service object
  driver = webdriver.Chrome("C:\\Users\\JRGN1\\PycharmProjects\\dynamic2\\chromedriver.exe")
Empty DataFrame
Columns: []
Index: []

Process finished with exit code 0

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
url = 'https://ec.europa.eu/info/law/better-regulation/have-your-say/initiatives_en'
driver.get(url)

# We save the article list
articles = WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, "//article")))

# We make a loop once per article in the loop
for i in range(1, len(articles)):
    # We save title, topic and period
    title = WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, f"(//article)[{i}]//div[2]"))).text
    print(title)
    topic = WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, f"(//article)[{i}]//div[3]/div[2]"))).text
    print(topic)
    period = WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, f"(//article)[{i}]//div[5]/div/div[2]"))).text
    print(period)
```

Once you have the info you can do whatever you want with it.

I hope it helps

Comment: Thanks a lot. Your code is running without errors but still gives me the same empty result as my code:
‘’’
C:\Users\JRGN1\PycharmProjects\pythonProject2\venv\Scripts\python.exe C:\Users\JRGN1\PycharmProjects\pythonProject2\main.py 
C:\Users\JRGN1\PycharmProjects\pythonProject2\main.py:7: DeprecationWarning: executable_path has been deprecated, please pass in a Service object
  driver = webdriver.Chrome("C:\\Users\\JRGN1\\PycharmProjects\\dynamic2\\chromedriver.exe")
Empty DataFrame
Columns: []
Index: []

Process finished with exit code 0
‘’’

Comment: But your problem is with selenium or with pandas (Saving the data)?

Comment: with selenium. The pandas work, so an empty csv document is created

Comment: Buy with selenium can not be the problem, because as you can see with the script you can get the title, topic etc... So, take them and save them

Comment: Hhhmmm, but the title and so on do not appear in the output. I have once seen someone do something similar and there the scraped data were part of the output before being stored in the csv file. You could actively watch the data being scraped, while I just get: Columns: [] Index: []